# inotify watcher stops working after ls or watch commands

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I took the code below from the [many examples](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/04/getting-started-with-inotify/) on the internet about how to use inotify.

I then tried the following experiment:
1) run the watcher below
2) in a separate shell, cd into `'/mypath'` create some files to the folder you are watching. For example, `'date > output.txt'` one ore more times.
3) you will see notifications from the watcher.
4) type `'ls /mypath'` (or even `'watch -n 1 /mypath'`)
5) try `'date > output.txt'` in /mypath. You will no longer see notifications from the watcher. Or at least, this is what happened when I tested with Ubuntu 12/13.

Any ideas about how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_EVENTS 1024 /*Max. number of events to process at one go*/
#define LEN_NAME 16 /*Assuming that the length of the filename won't exceed 16 bytes*/
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) ) /*size of one event*/
#define BUF_LEN     ( MAX_EVENTS * ( EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME )) /*buffer to store the data of events*/

int main() 
{
  int length, i = 0, wd;
  int fd;
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];

  /* Initialize Inotify*/
   fd = inotify_init();
  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "Couldn't initialize inotify");
  }

  /* add watch to starting directory */
  wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/mypath", IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE); 

  if (wd == -1)
    {
      printf("Couldn't add watch to %s\n","/mypath");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Watching:: %s\n","/mypath");
    }

  /* do it forever*/
  while(1)
    {  
      i = 0;
      length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  


      if ( length < 0 ) {
        perror( "read" );
      }  

      while ( i < length ) {
        struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
        if ( event->len ) {
          if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE) {
            if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
              printf( "The directory %s was Created.\n", event->name );       
            else
              printf( "The file %s was closed (write) with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );       
          }
          if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE) {
            if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
              printf( "The directory %s was Created.\n", event->name );       
            else
              printf( "The file %s was closed (nowrite) with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );       
          }



          i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
      }     
    }

  /* Clean up*/
  inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
  close( fd );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you try with the `inotifywait` command line (for ubuntu that's in `inotify-tools` package) instead of your own executable?

Comment: Dont forget to award the bounty by clicking the +200 under the tick on your selected answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put `i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;` inside the `if ( event->len )` block. If an event has a zero-length name, then the pointer should still be incremented by `EVENT_SIZE` (which is what will happen if you put that statement outside the block). I think you might be seeing an infinite loop in your inotify program, kicked off by the first event which happens to have a zero-length name. (Which is exactly what happens with the `ls`: The directory is being opened, not its files, so there's nothing in the `name` field.)

Comment: so basically you suggest putting it right after the brackets that follows it in the code above right?

Answer (score 1):

You get into an ever-ending loop since you do not change `i` when `event->len == 0`
Add this:

```
else
    i += EVENT_SIZE ;
```

in case `if ( event->len == 0 )`

Comment: That is definitely going to screw stuff up further. `i` is a byte counter. It doesn't index the events.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when your program stops working it eats all the CPU. I made a few changes and it seems to work now. Here are the details:

Declare BUF_LEN to handle 16 events (you can increase that value):

```
#define BUF_LEN (16 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1))
```

Change your `while (i < length)` loop that processes the events to the following for loop:

```
for ( p = buffer; p < buffer + length; ) {
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) p;
    p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
    if ( event->len ) {
        /* SNIP */
    }
}
```

The `p` variable should be declared as `char *` and you can remove the `i` which is not used anymore.